# Iron router params empty

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Yesterday I updated meteor and my meteorite packages to their latest versions. Today, iron router is not behaving. When I navigate to a parameterized route, the parameter is not loaded. What gives? I have looked at the documentation for iron-router, and it still specifies the same scheme I was using before.

This is the routes file I have created

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
  });

  this.route('list', {
    path: '/:_id',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('lists')
    },
    data: function() {
      var list = Lists.findOne({
        _id: this.params._id
      });
      Session.set('listId', list._id);
      return list;
    }
  });
});
```

When I load a page to `http://localhost/1234` the path in iron router is correctly set to `/1234` but it does not recognize the last bit as a parameter.

Comment: I just copied your code and it worked for me. Inserted `console.log(this.params._id)` at the top of the data function. Using iron-router 0.8.2 and Meteor 0.8.3.

Comment: BTW, `onBeforeAction` is always a better place to set `Session` variables since `data` hook will be recomputed every time this output from your query changes.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that what is empty is not your `this.params` object but rather the `list` document, at least for the first time the route is being executed. This is caused, of course, by the latency related to fetching server data.

You may be thinking that it shouldn't happen because you have used the `waitOn` hook. But for this to work you would also need to do two other things:

```
Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

and define the loading template:

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'someTemplateName'
});
```

so please update if you haven't done it already.

Comment: You're correct about the loading template not being used (I'll make a GH issue on this later) but the problem was resolved by `git clone`ing a new repo and doing `meteor update` and `mrt update` in that new repo. It looks like something got messed up during the previous update and doing a fresh install fixed it.

Comment: I am happy you fixed it!